# Create new file on windows

Tags: windows-7-x64

I'm using windows 7 Ultimate.
While press right button mouse there is no "New" option...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNBNM.png)
And also while press the "New folder" button there no folder created.
It just shows the "New Folder" button is pressed but no such thing happen..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWAhr.png)

Help me to fix this...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the white space of the window, you seem to have something selected on your first picture.

also you could try
ctrl + shift + n

this is the hot keys for creating a new folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried in the process you told. but same thing shows. And while i press ctrl+shift+n nothing happen.

Thanks...

Comment: Hmm, wow, sounds like your system explorer is totally messed up... hmm i assume you have tried to restart your windows? Sounds like the process is failing?
Sry I am at a loss at this point